# How to return future object from callable interface (internal working of executorService.submit)

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to understand how future object is created when running the `executorService.submit(Callable);`

For example lets say I create a thread pool in which I pass my implementation of callable

```
class FactorialCalculator implements Callable<Long> { 
  private int number; 
  public FactorialCalculator(int number) { 
    this.number = number; 
  } 
  @Override 
  public Long call() throws Exception { 
        return (number*number); 
  }
}
```

I want to return the future object so I can get the return value from call function. My custom thread pool looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123457/internal-working-of-newfixedthreadpool)

```
class MyThreadPool implements java.util.concurrent.Executor 
{
    private final java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue<Callable> queue;

    public MyThreadPool(int numThreads) {
        queue = new java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        for (int i=0 ; i<numThreads ; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(true) {
                        queue.take().call();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void submit(Callable command) {
        queue.put(command);
    }
}
```

Now if I do

```
MyThreadPool mypool = new MyThreadPool(10);
mypool.submit(new FactorialCalculator(10));
```

I want to submit method to return future so I can check the return value if the thread has finished execution. How do I return future object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to wrap your callable in a FutureTask:

```
@Override
public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> callable) {
    FutureTask<T> future = new FutureTask(callable);
    queue.put(future);
    return future;
}
```

Of course, the *even easier* solution would be to use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` instead of reimplementing it on your own.