# how to override executorService shutdown method

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, shutdown

I am creating my own thread pool and future object which can execute callable interface parallel. Executor provides shutdown method to stop all worker threads from running. If i am creating a thread pool like below how should I implement the shutdown method to stop after all threads have finished execution?

My custom thread pool looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123457/internal-working-of-newfixedthreadpool)

```
class MyThreadPool implements java.util.concurrent.Executor 
{
    private final java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue<Callable> queue;

    public MyThreadPool(int numThreads) {
        queue = new java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        for (int i=0 ; i<numThreads ; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(true) {
                        queue.take().call();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

  @Override
  public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> callable) {
    FutureTask<T> future = new FutureTask(callable);
    queue.put(future);
    return future;
  }

  public void shutdown(){ }
}
```

I couldnt think of a way to keep list of thread and then check if they are idle or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely should hold references to the threads you're creating. For instance, set up a field `threads` of type `List<Thread>` and add the threads to this list from within the constructor.

Afterwards, you could implement `shutdown()` with the help of [`Thread#join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--):

```
public void shutdown() {
    for (Thread t : threads) {
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* NOP */ }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to replace `while (true)` with an appropriate condition (which you toggle in `shutdown()`) and consider using [`BlockingQueue#poll(long, TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) rather than `take()`.

**EDIT:** Something like:

```
public class MyThreadPool implements Executor {

    private List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    private BlockingDeque<Callable> tasks = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    public MyThreadPool(int numberOfThreads) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
                while (running) {
                    try {
                        Callable c = tasks.poll(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        if (c != null) {
                            c.call();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) { /* NOP */ }
                }
            });
            t.start();
            threads.add(t);
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        running = false;
        for (Thread t : threads) {
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* NOP */ }
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: i beileve the reason is becuause the thread is is wait condition for taking callable from the queue hence it does not terminate. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: yes this works although I dont want to poll for my queue. I however used the poison pill approach in my shutdown method. What i did was added a poison object in queue in shutdown method and when i take it from the queue i check if it poison. If yes I break out of the loop

Comment: @krs8888 Glad that did help. Feel free to accept the answer if your problem has been solved.